# RegExp extract value from pipe delimited string

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql, delimiter

I'm quite new to regexp function and wanted some advice.
I have a field which contains pipe delimited values and looking to extract a value based on a position of another value.
Reason for this is that the value I want is not always set, but always tends to come in the 5th position of another value. Hope I am making sense so far.

Here is an example of the string:

|XYZ|CBA|**365**|15841.25|43.40|20171202|20181201|**365**|17024.94|46.64||20171202|20181201|**365**|17024.94|46.64||0.00|***546.18***|0000|

I want to extract the figure thats bold and italicised  - 546.18 and it tends to come at the 5th position after the third '365', or the first 365 from the bottom up and this is what i would prefer.

I have tried reversing the string and getting the first instance of 365

first step - reverse the field (content)
reverse(content) as content_rev

second step -  to bring back first 55 characters from first instance of 563 and reverse string back to original

reverse(substr(content_rev, instr(content_rev, '\|563\|')-50, 55)) as extract_content

Output looks like:
|365|17024.94|46.64||0.00|***546.18***|8528|02|0540023096|2|2

from this point not sure how to get the highlighted value

I'm sure this way is not the most efficient method, so if anyone has a better method to get the result, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: **461.01** <-- I don't actually see this value in your pipe-delimited data.

Comment: Also, are you using MySQL or Hive?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: sorry im using hive sql, ive corrected the figure it should be 546.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split using | as delimiter and take 5th element.

```
split(your_string, '\\|')[5]
```

where your_string is what you get using reverse, etc: `|365|17024.94|46.64||0.00|546.18|8528|02|0540023096|2|2`